# Enforce Flash wmode = window on Mac

Tags: flash, macos, swfobject, wmode

How do I enforce Flash's wmode=window on Mac? This mode should make Flash reside on a layer higher than normal HTML elements and have better performance. It's working fine on Windows. On Mac, there's strange results. Chrome on Mac will allow HTML elements to cover only non-video elements in Flash. On the other hand, Firefox on Mac will let HTML elements cover *anything* in Flash. I don't want to allow *any* HTML elements to cover *anything* in Flash on Mac.

I'm using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed my Flash.

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
    'flash/player_20110128.swf',
    'flashPlayer',
    '100%',
    '100%',
    '9',
    'expressInstallSwfUrlTODO.swf',
    {},
    {
        allowfullscreen: true, 
        wmode: 'window'
    },
    {},
    function(status) {
        if (!status.success) {
            alert('Failed to embed Flash player');
        } else {
            alert('embedded');
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gave you tried wmode=direct?

> "Direct" instructs the player to
>   totally bypass the parent web browser
>   for rendering. You might compare it to
>   standalone players performance with
>   the little more kick.

It requires flash player 10 and beyond though.

Comment: Do I need to view with Flash 10 or author with Flash 10? When I view with Flash Player 10, but authoring with Flash CS3 (Flash 9), and set wmode=direct, I still get the same layering problems.